# overridePendingTransition() method does not work for when we move the activities on Back key press?

Tags: android, animation

I have 3 activities A,B,C.I am able to show the animations when move the activity from A->B->C.

I want to add the animation when I press the back buton.

I am using overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein,R.anim.fadeout) on onCreate() method.

Can some one explain how it works when i pressed the back button?

Comment: What happens when you try  the method suggested by `goodm`

Answer (score 1):

Override your activity's `onBackPressed`

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override back button:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
    {
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_out, R.anim.anim_in);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

For exammple:
Create "anim" folder in res and add:
anim_out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

anim_in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

Comment: I tried it does not work for me. fadein:
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="400"                                             fadeout:                                              android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="400"

Comment: Try change "100%p" to "100%"

Comment: I tried with above XML files.But still its not showing the effect.

Comment: I have three Activities.on all three activities i have mentioned overridePendingTransition(R.anim.createin,R.anim.createout) in onCreate Method.So it is working when I moving the activites.                  Same way i added this method overridePendingTransition(R.anim.destroyin,R.anim.destroyout) in all three activity onKeyDown() method.but When I press the Back key whatever i mentioned in the onCreate() method that animation effect is showing,,that means forward and backward same effect it is showing even though if we mentioned different XML files.

Comment: Change order in animation when you override onKeyDown() like this: overridePendingTransition(R.anim.destrout,R.anim.destroyin)